# Automatically declaring and initialising variables

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# programming, so I decided to develop myself by trying out a few basic programming tasks. One of such is a calculator, and I've pretty much cracked it, except that I want the calculator to accept all the values first, before computing - unlike a lot of the ones I've seen online, where the first two values are computed, then the third is computed with the result of those two.

My thoughts are to declare only one variable at compile time, then whenever a user clicks on an operator, a new variable is created to accept the value passed in afterwards. No calculations will be made until all the values have been accepted, and the equals button clicked.

Got any ideas?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal can you recommend any good ones? By the way, I don't like the tone of your reply.

Answer (score 0):

As Far I got your Question.. U should keep collection of values and operators.. It is all up to u that u want single collection for both values and operators or separator and also u maintain stack format or queue..

Here collection can be any thing. like list, array etc..